# wordpress ENGIMA theme- removing social media icon

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to remove only instagram icon from my page

[image of icons before putting code in child theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/511WK.png)

but when I put this code in child theme of engima (style.css)

```
.social li.facebook {
 display: none
         }
```

It will remove facebook icon also.

[image of icons after putting code in child theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dffYw.png)

Both have same class name in the theme

```
<li class="facebook" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Facebook"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>

<li class="facebook" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="instagram"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the class of the instagram logo to instagram. Then use this css code:

```
.social li.instagram {
    display: none;
}
```

If you don't want to change the class name (which I don't recommend) you can use:

```
.social li.facebook:nth-child(2) {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to use any CSS to remove the icon. The theme checks to see if the value for a social network is set in the theme options and if it is, the theme will display that icon. If the option is blank the theme won't display that icon.

Follow the steps below to change the Theme Options

1. Login to the admin area
2. Navigate to **Appearance > Customize** in the left sidebar
3. Expand **Theme Options** in the left sidebar
4. Open **Social Options** in the left sidebar
5. Scroll to the instragram field and remove any text in the textbox so
   that it is blank
6. Once you are done with your changes click the blue **Save and Publish**
   button at the top of the sidebar menu.

This is tested on Enigma Theme 2.4.2